# mapping command mode on iPad

Tags: vim, ios

On my Mac, I put the following in my `.vimrc` to use `ii` as the  key. Note, I include the `:` in the .vimrc file, i'm not sure if you're supposed to but it still works :)

```
:imap ii <Esc>
```

I'm now trying to setup Vim on my iPad (see http://applidium.com/en/applications/vim/). Since there's no <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the iPad, the developers who ported Vim mapped the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to <kbd>\</kbd>, however <kbd>\</kbd> is very inconvenient if you're using the native iPad keyboard (rather than the bluetooth), so I'm trying to remap it again in the .vimrc that I've imported into the iPad via iTunes.

I put this in the .vimrc, thinking I should remap the remap

```
`:imap ii \`
```

but it always types two <kbd>i</kbd> rather then enter command mode.

What should I put in the `.vimrc` to make the Vim enter command mode on the iPad by pressing `ii`. I'm not sure if something special has to be done to remap a remap.

the `.vimrc` file where `ii` mapping still prints `ii` rather than escaping

```
syntax on
set autoindent
set number
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set ruler
set number

set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase

let mapleader = "\<space>"
nmap <leader>h <C-W>h
nmap <leader>j <C-W>j
nmap <leader>k <C-W>k
nmap <leader>l <C-W>l
:imap ii <esc>
```

Comment: If it were `.exrc`, the `:` would be required, but for `.vimrc` the `:` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Just map it to `<esc>`:

```
:imap ii <esc>
```

Even though iDevices don't support the escape key, Vim still recognizes the notation for escape in mappings, etc.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it still prints `ii` everytime, no matter how quickly i press `ii` (note on my laptop I use `ii` mapping without problem). I posted the whole .vimrc file in the OP for you to see

Comment: That is very strange.  What does the output of `:scriptnames` and `:verbose imap ii` show?

Comment: I took a screenshot on the iPad of the output of those commands, see here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10328969/vim.PNG

Comment: I was able to try testing it on my iTouch. So far I can't make it work no matter what I do. Looks like a bug, which isn't surprising considering how much the people who ported Vim had to do to make it work.